# How long is the beta period?

Tags: discussion, private-beta

I'm wondering how long typically the private beta period will last? I could not find info on the cs.SE/FAQ (or maybe I missed it).

Answer (score 5):

Private betas are evaluated after 7 days. Most become public betas at that point. Sometimes, a private beta that hasn't had enough traffic or that's perceived as low quality might be told to shape up and given an extra period of time to improve.

I must say I'm a bit concerned that our beta is too slow. While there aren't any hard-and-fast rules, we only have 60 questions after 5 days. Even [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/), where traffic later dwindled to a trickle, had 125 questions in its 7-day private beta. 16 unanswered questions is another concern; many of these are difficult questions, but it does mean we really need to work on recruiting experts on a broad range of fields.

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping that the thundering hordes from SO might show up after the beta opens up :)

Comment: @Suresh Which is both potential and risk. We will have to take extra care to keep our level (of answers) clearly distinct from SO.

Comment: We decided to extend this private beta another 7 days. The question count is a bit on the low side to launch and that gives you a bit more time to flesh out the scope and let the community self-moderation take a bit more hold.